# Distance Matrix API / java

Tags: java, google-distancematrix-api

I have a java program which calculates the distance and the journey time between two locations using the google matrix distance API. when I run my program everything goes fine but after a while I get this error:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message `"java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out"`

suggests that the root cause of the problem is due to network connectivity failure.  This could have been caused due to these issues:

1. Google Distance API is a paid service, which requires billing account. Connectivity to API may fail when quota / billing had exhausted.
2. API requires a key for authorization. Connectivity can fail if the key had expired.
3. Network connectivity failed between the client computer and the API had failed, possibly due to a faulty internet connection.

Verifying the billing account, API key and network connectivity can help resolve the issue.